# c++ using recursion instead of for loop

Tags: c++

I have a code below

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int n){
     if(n == 0) {return;}
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;
}

int main(){
   print(n);
}
```

What it does is it prints "Hello world" using for loop n times. My question is would it be possible to print it using recursion instead of using for loop?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible.

Comment: remove the `for` part, and after the `cout` add `print(n-1);`.

Comment: This feels like a homework question.

Comment: In the **iterative** version, `if(n == 0) {return;}` is unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt your code like this. The `print` function will be called recursively `n` times, then return since in the last call `n` will be equal to `0` and because of the first condition it will stop the recursion.

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int n) {
     if(n == 0) { return; }
     std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
     print(n-1);
}

int main(){
   print(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is simply a function that calls itself. There's a pretty good tutorial [HERE](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/recursion).

Basically, you would create a counter, and add to that counter every time the function is called, and don't call it from inside itself if the counter is higher than a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do something like this:

```c
#include <iostream>

void print(int n){
     if(n!=0){
         std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
         return print(n-1);
     }
}

int main(){  
   print(n);
   return 0;
}
```